# how to process dynamic urls as static pages using nginx?

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, content-management-system, static-pages

I want my Nginx serve dynamical urls as static pages, e.g.

```
given a url  "/book?name=ruby_lang&published_at=2014" , 
the nginx will serve a static file (which is generated automatically ) named as:
"book?name=ruby_lang&published_at=2014.html"  or:
"book-name-eq-ruby_lang-pblished_at-eq-2014.html"
```

is this possible?

NOTE:

1.there's no static file named:

```
  "book?name=ruby_lang&published_at=2014.html" nor 
  "book-name-eq-ruby_lang-pblished_at-eq-2014.html"
```

however, I can generate them if needed.

2.I can't change the url that give to the consumer. e.g. my consumer could only send request to me via

```
  "/book?name=ruby_lang&published_at=2014"
```

but not with any other urls.

Comment: What do you mean by "serve as static"? Do you have file named "book-name-eq-ruby_lang-pblished_at-eq-2014.html"?

Comment: does your CMS support custom URL's ?

Comment: Is the file really static or generated on demand? Is it only that specific URL that you need to support or some URL scheme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are OK with generating the HTML files yourself, you could simply use nginx's rewrite module. Example:

```
rewrite ^/book book-name-eq-$arg_name-published_at-eq-$arg_published_at.html last;
```

If you need to make sure that `name` and `published_at` are valid, you can instead do something like this:

```
location = /book {
    if ($arg_name !~ "^[A-Za-z\d_-]+$") { return 404; }
    if ($arg_published_at !~ "^\d{4}$") { return 404; }
    rewrite ^/book book-name-eq-$arg_name-published_at-eq-$arg_published_at.html last;
}
```

This will make sure that `published_at` is a valid 4-digits integer, and `name` is a valid identifier (English alphabets, numbers, underscore, and hyphen).

---

To make sure a book is only accessible from one URL, you should throw 404 if the URL is the HTML file. Add this *before* the previous rule:

```
location ~ /book-(.*).html {
    return 404;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to @Alon Gubkin's help, finally I solved this problem, (see : http://siwei.me/blog/posts/nginx-try-files-and-rewrite-tips) .here are some tips:

1. use 'try_files' instead of 'rewrite'
2. use '-' instead of underscore '_' in your static file names, otherwise nginx would get confused when setting $arg_parameters to your file name. e.g. use "platform-$arg_platform.json' instead of "platform_$arg_platform.json"
3. take a look at [nginx built-in variables](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24args).

and this is my nginx config snippet:

```
server {
  listen       100;
  charset utf-8;
  root /workspace/test_static_files;
  index index.html index.htm;

  # nginx will first search '/platform-$arg_platform...' file, 
  # if not found return /defautl.json 
  location /popup_pages {
    try_files /platform-$arg_platform-product-$arg_product.json /default.json;
  } 
}
```

also I put my code on github so that someone interested in this issue could take a look:
https://github.com/sg552/server_dynamic_urls_as_static_files

Comment: buddy, all the Chinese is followed by English translation.  good luck!